# A good google.maps geolocation api?

Tags: html, api, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

Is there a google maps api that will allow you to pass in a location name and it will return coordinates that point to the location on googlemaps?

Comment: I didn't even know that the Google Maps Data API is no longer available: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/ they offer an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Here is a example request:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Berlin&sensor=false`

You can filter the result: for `geometry/location/lat` and `lng`

```
<GeocodeResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
    <result>
    <type>locality</type>
    <type>political</type>
    <formatted_address>Berlin, Deutschland</formatted_address>
    […]
    <geometry>
      <location>
        <lat>52.5234051</lat>
        <lng>13.4113999</lng>
      </location>
      <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
      <viewport>[…]</viewport>
      <bounds>[…]</bounds>
    </geometry>
  </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, need to use reverse geolocation. You can send an address or location string and it will give you an array of the possible lat/Long coordinates for it. These are [GeocoderResults](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderResult) and normally the first one is what you want. Like, if you wanted the USA you could do

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': 'USA' }, function(results, status) {
  response($.map(results, function(item) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lng()); 
    //Do some action with the provided latlng
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mappy also provide a same free service. Have a look to mappy.com and search for rest api.